# How many arrays does array_chunk return?

Tags: php, arrays

How could i know the amount of arrays that php chunk function returns?

For example, if i execute this piece of code i know that it'll return 3 arrays, but how could i calculate it:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Comment: What do you mean calculate it? If you want to know how many arrays are returned after chunking, just use `count()` ?

Comment: Simply use `count` if you need to calculate it `echo count(array_chunk($input_array, 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it programmatically by dividing the number of values in the array that should be chunked by the chunk size:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$chunkSize = 2;
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, $chunkSize));


$count = round(count($input_array) / $chunkSize,PHP_ROUND_UP);
```

I'm using `PHP_ROUND_UP` because the last chunk doesn't neccessarly have all the chunk size values, but is an array, too.

Comment: Is the same through the flag @JonathanS.

Answer (score 3):

You would want something like

```
ceil ( count ( $input_array ) / $chunk_size);
```

In your case

5/2 = 2.5

After the ceil function result = 3